# Bending corners inwards on gauge with CSS in Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

The code looks exactly like in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-moon-t08hp?file=/src/App.js) codesandbox.

Is it possible to somehow bend the corners inwards where the gauge starts and ends on the bottom and make the corners more round?

I have tried to use `&:before` and `&:after` by masking with shapes over the ends, but can't figure it out. Anyone who is able to help?

I have attached two images as examples of what I want to achieve. [image: image1] [image: image2]

Any help is appreciated!